# Is it possible for code to change without Git knowing about it?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, git, unit-testing, testing, solid-state-drive

This morning I ran my tests and there are 2 failures. But I haven't changed any code for a few days and all tests were passing.

According to Git, there are no changes (except for coverage.data, which is the test output). gitk shows no other changes.

How does Git know when code changes? Could this be caused by an SSD failure/error?

What is the best way to figure out what happened?

EDIT: Working in Ruby on Rails with Unit Test framework.

Comment: Since it is failing today, see if it is some date issue on last day of a month, especially one with 31 days.

Comment: That was it. Fails on last day of month.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I'd start by figuring out why the tests failed, and that might give you some clues as to how they might have passed before.  Sometimes it's a timing issue, intermittent failure, something external to the test harness, data changing, a change of date or time, all sorts of stuff.

Comment: Yes, it is a timing issue. Calculating Date.today - 6.months + 6.months. Fails on the last day of the month that has 31 days! (As well as August 29 (on non-leap years) and 30, I think).

Comment: Yup you're right about that.  When I run `DateTime.Today.AddMonths(-6).AddMonths(6).ToShortDateString();` under the debugger, I get `10/30/2011' - It seems when I subtract 6mon, I'll get back to April 30th (since Apr has no day 31), but then when I add 6mon to that, I'll get Oct 30th.  I guess this makes sense.

Answer (score 9):

I see Mike found your problem (ticky the little answer box please).

Yes, it is possible for code to change without Git knowing about it.  The file which caused the failure, perhaps a temporary testing file or fixture, could be ignored either in .gitignore or .git/info/exclude.  Doing a `git clean -dxf` will wipe the checkout clean of anything not known to git.  `git status --ignored` will show the files ignored by git.  If that's the case, you want to add better test cleanup as part of your test runner.

For posterity, here's the short list of ways tests could fail without there being any code change visible to git:

- "Temporary" test files and fixtures might be dirty.
- "Temporary" databases and tables might be dirty.
- It is sensitive to time or date.
- It uses network resources and they changed.
- The compiler was changed.
- The installed libraries used were changed.

  - The libraries the libraries use were changed.
- The kernel was changed.
- Any servers used (databases, web servers, etc...) were changed.
- It uses parallel processing and a subtle bug only occurs sometimes.
- The disk (or the filesystem where temp files go) is full.
- The disk (or the filesystem where temp files go) is broken.
- Your memory/disk/process/filehandle quotas were reduced.
- The machine has run out of memory.
- The machine has run out of filehandles.
- It uses fixtures with randomly generated data and generated some that tickled a bug.

Answer (score 2):

Your repository can't have any changes without Git knowing about it and logging it somewhere since it's necessary to retrieve the logs to be able to get the repo files anyways. I would check to see that the failures aren't caused by something on the machine that shouldn't be running at the same time as the tests or it could possibly be a race condition that you're not expecting.